# What is the significance of directions when using vector entites ( velocity, acceleration ) in space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, education

The role direction if ( up, down), seems understandable when using the vector entities like velocity and acceleration on earth. Because the overall output changes, when the same object goes up as opposed to when it goes down. So the direction plays role, in calculations.

But when in space, there is no such thing called direction. There is no up, no down, left or right etc. Do vector quantities still need directions in that case ? Do they change the output for different directions ( like on earth ).

If not, is their any significance of "vectors" while calculating motion in space ?

Comment: A direction in space signifies motion along an infinite line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **But when in space, there is no such thing called direction.**

In space, you have to first choose a frame of reference in order to measure or calculate vector quantities. The choice is arbitrary but whatever choice you make, you will end up with the same answer. Some choices make the calculations easier.

For example, you could identify a nearby small blue-green looking planet and arbitrarily assign the name "down" to the direction towards the centre of mass of that planet. Or you could choose a faraway star.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the idea that there is no such thing as direction in space?

I assume you're confusing the microgravity in a spacecraft with "no direction". Indeed, in a completely enclosed spacecraft, without windows, you cannot tell which way the earth (or the moon, the sun, etc) are. However, they are still very much in a particular direction, even if you cannot sense it in any way.

And, if you start the rocket engine in your spacecraft, you will very much feel which way is "down" - which of course may not be the direction of the earth. In that case, "down" will be towards the engine, and "up" is the other way. Hence, the acceleration you feel definitely has a direction, and thus is a vector. The same goes for velocity, although in space you cannot feel velocity at all.